# Is it wrong if I broke my fast intentionally because I fainted and was feeling very dizzy?

Tags: sawm

I broke my fast because I fainted and was feeling very dizzy. Is this wrong? Would this be considered intentionally or unintentionally breaking a fast?

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar question which was asked:

> What is the ruling of Fainting and anesthesia (unconscious) at the
>   time of the fasting?

The presented answer which can be related to your question was that:

> If you already have had the intention of the fasting, it is considered
>   as the precaution (Mustahab, recommended) to end the fasting of that
>   day and afterwards do its Qaza as well (repeat it).

Hence fainting doesn’t appear including the items which invalidate the fasting. Then you mustn’t break your fast in such positions (since fainting doesn’t invalidate that). Based on my limited knowledge, you should do it again (Qaza), since you broke it, but I am not sure if you must do it with Kaffara (60…) or not. Hopefully, my answer can be helpful for you to some extent.

---

**References:**

- [www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=281677)
- [www.sistani.org](http://www.sistani.org/persian/book/50/70/)
- [ahkam2.mihanblog.com](http://ahkam2.mihanblog.com/post/59)

Comment: Fainting during fasting can exhibit an underlying medical problem and could very well be harmful. I believe in every case of fainting you should break your fast, and seek medical advice. It could be as simple as dehydration or something more significant.

Comment: @masfenix Nice matter you mentioned. Of course I said that regarding if it would be invalid or not. Otherwise I reckon perhaps they should break their fasting if it considers as a remarkable harm... / Good luck mate

Answer (score 1):

In this case it does not matter whether it is considered intentionally or unintentionally breaking the fast.

You fainted and you felt dizzy. It is wrong not to break the fast. In particular when you have strong reasons to believe that you are not well/healthy.

Au contraire, would you have not broken the fast you might have taken a bad decision. Especially when you are in a position in which you are supposed to be an example for others. You might mislead others in thinking that *no matter the condition* you have to finish the fast. You are responsible.

Simply catch up on that day during the coming year. God is merciful.

On a side note, you are encouraged to ponder. Think about what might have caused the fainting and dizziness, and try to mitigate if you can. Should you have reasons to believe that it might be a condition consult a doctor.